# Limiting operations within sets, or intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I just have a question about using limits with union and intersection operations.

To prove the claim that *the intersection of infinite collection of open sets may not be open* (side question: is it possible for such an intersection to be open?), a common textbook example is goes something like: consider the intersection of sets defined by

$$G_n = (0, 1+ 1/n)$$

where it is clear that every set is open. From here, the argument from two of my sources pretty much goes as follows: the intersection of such sets is $(0, 1]$, which is not open. The end.

I understand that, and believe it. But I'm not sure how they applied the limiting operation with the intersection involved. The best argument I could come up with was just saying, well, $(0,1]$ is definitely contained in the intersection of all those sets and that for any $\epsilon_1 > 0$ in $(0, 1+ \epsilon_1)$ we can generate another set $(0, 1+ \epsilon_2)$ where $\epsilon_2 < \epsilon_1$ by *blah blah*... so that $1 + \epsilon_1 \notin (0, 1+ \epsilon_2) \cap  (0, 1+ \epsilon_1)$. I know that's true. But is that a good way of finding this intersection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They did ***not*** apply a limiting operation.

Addition is a binary operation, so when you want to add more than two things, you need to repeatedly add two things over and over until you work through them. This can only ever add finitely many things, so to do infinite sums you do a limiting operation.

Intersection, however, is an operation on arbitrary collections of sets. You don't repeatedly take pairwise intersections and then a limit — you just take the intersection of everything in one "step".

The definition is that $x \in \cap_{i \in I} X_i$  if and only if $x \in X_i$ for every $i \in I$. In the specific example:

> $ x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(0, 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) $
>   if and only if, for every integer $n \geq 1$, you have $x \in \left(0, 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)$

For $x > 1$, you can show that there exists an $n$ such that $x \notin \left(0, 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$, and thus you conclude that $x \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(0, 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)$.

Comment: (+1) It is also true, though, that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ is the limit (in a pretty natural sense) of $\bigcap_{i=1}^n X_i$ for $n\to\infty$. We just don't need to use that as a _definition_ because a more direct definition is available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can say that if 
$$
0<x< 1+\frac{1}{n}
$$
for all $n$, then taking $n\to \infty$ and using properties of limits and inequalities  we have that
$$
0<x\leq 1
$$
so that
$$
\bigcap_{1}^\infty(0,1+n^{-1})\subset (0,1] .
$$
It is easy to see that the reverse containment holds.